# Start OWIN TestServer from mstest.exe

Tags: c#, unit-testing, owin, mstest

I have a working unit test that sets up a TestServer, creates requests and validates the response.

When I run those unit tests from Visual Studio Test Explorer, they work great. The TestServer is set up, requests are made and the correct response returned.

When I run the same code from the command line (on our CI server), the TestServer always returns a status code for "Not Found". There are no other exceptions. Are there any specific commands that I need to add when starting OWIN from the command line?

The MSTest.exe command looks like this:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:myTests.dll /resultsfile:testresults.trx
```

My Test Method looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetToken()
{
   using (var server = TestServer.Create<TestStartupConfiguration>())
   {
      var response = await server.CreateRequest("/TokenUrl").And(x => x.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
       {
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", user.UserName),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", user.Password),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
        })).PostAsync();

       response.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().BeTrue("this is the expected return value of an Access Token request");
       var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       responseString.Should().NotBeNullOrWhiteSpace("the response of an Access Token request should not be empty");
    }
}
```

And, as I said, the test works fine from within Visual Studio. And all other unit tests are executed from the command line as expected.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your build setup to restore NuGet packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The `NotFound` error came because the OAuth configuration I wanted to test had the `AllowInsecureHttp` property set to `false` when running as a Unit test. I made sure that `AllowInsecureHttp` is `true` not only in `DEBUG` mode but also when a Unit test is running.

Now it works perfectly.